# spilt text files to tsv UTF-8 with headers in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Im using the below code for splitting the huge file into 20K TSV UTF-8 files..

**However, i need every split files should have the header in the 20k count, how we can do it?**

```css
$sourceFile = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\DE.txt"
$partNumber = 1
$batchSize = 20000
$pathAndFilename = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\Temp part $partNumber file.tsv"

[System.Text.Encoding]$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(65001)  # utf8 this one

$fs=New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($sourceFile,"OpenOrCreate", "Read", "ReadWrite",8,"None") 
$streamIn=New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($fs, $enc)
$streamout = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $pathAndFilename

$line = $streamIn.readline()
$counter = 0
while ($line -ne $null)
{
    $streamout.writeline($line)
    $counter +=1
    if ($counter -eq $batchsize)
    {
        $partNumber+=1
        $counter =0
        $streamOut.close()
        $pathAndFilename = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\Temp part $partNumber file.tsv"
        $streamout = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter $pathAndFilename

    }
    $line = $streamIn.readline()
}
$streamin.close()
$streamout.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without altering your code too much, you need to capture the header line in a variable and write that out first thing on every new file:

```
$sourceFile = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\DE.txt"
# using a template filename saves writing
$pathOut    = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\Temp part {0} file.tsv"
$partNumber = 1
$batchSize  = 20000  # max number of data lines to write in each part
# construct the output filename using the template $pathOut
$pathAndFilename = $pathOut -f $partNumber

$enc       = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$fs        = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($sourceFile,"Open", "Read")  # don't need write access on source file
$streamIn  = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($fs, $enc)
$streamout = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($pathAndFilename)

# assuming the first line contains the headers
$header = $streamIn.ReadLine()
# write out the header on the first part
$streamout.WriteLine($header)

$counter = 0
while (($line = $streamIn.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    $streamout.WriteLine($line)
    $counter++
    if ($counter -ge $batchsize) {
        $partNumber++
        $counter = 0
        $streamOut.Flush()
        $streamOut.Dispose()
        $pathAndFilename = $pathOut -f $partNumber
        $streamout = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($pathAndFilename)
        # write the header on this new part
        $streamout.WriteLine($header)
    }
}
$streamin.Dispose()
$streamout.Dispose()
$fs.Dispose()
```

Comment: One small clarification how do open the source file in UTF-8 format? I tried using $sourceFile = "C:\Users\lingaguru.c3\Desktop\Test\DE.txt" -Encoding UTF8 but not working

Comment: @Linga Not quite sure what you intend to do there, but if you want to read the file in PowerShell, just do `Get-Content -Path $SourceFile -Encoding UTF8`. This will read the file line-by-line. You can also add switch `-Raw` to that, with which the file is read as one single string. However, if the file is huge you may run out of memory..